# Colission testing with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tetris

Let's say I have a cell-matrix and coordinates `x`, `y` which denote the top-left cell of a `Tetronimo` and a Matrix `B` corresponding to a Tetris well:

```
T = [[2,2,2],
     [2,0,0],
     [0,0,0]]

y,x = (1,0)

B = [[0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0],
     [1,0,0,0,0],]
```

Currently I'm using simple comparison to find collision:

```
def testCollision(x,y, T, B):
    for dx in xrange(3):
        for dy in xrange(3):
            if T[dy][dx] == 0:
                continue
            else:
                if B[y+dy][x + dx] != 0:
                    return False
    return True
```

Can I speed this up with the use of numpy?

Comment: How did you have `3` in `for dx in xrange(3)`. Is it the number of rows in `T`? Simlarly for the columns iterator?

Comment: Yes, I altered the example a bit, `3` is the number of rows and cols in T.

Comment: So, in your actual case, how big are `T` and `B`?

Comment: `2` for the `O` Tetronimo and up to `4` for `I`: [This](http://i.imgur.com/wjDP5Q2.png) is a complete list..

Comment: And that small dataset is taking `300ms`?

Comment: Within the numpy paradigm, I suppose it will be better to use identical stencil sizes (5x5) for all tetronimos; more iteration, but also a lot more vectorization. The latter is more significant, in all likelihood

Comment: I'll try that, but do you have a idea how I could solve those cases where `T` overlaps `B` to the right or left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, something of this form should work

```
return (B[x:x+3,y:y+3] * T).sum() == 0
```

You should test it for correctness; in any case it will be algorithmically optimal, within the numpy paradigm. Note however, that operations on small arrays such as these are not terribly efficient either. Still a lot better than C-style iteration, but the overhead of the array abstraction will be noticeable. That is, insofar performance is an issue in the first place, when it comes to Tetris. ;)

```
return (B[x:,y:][:3,:3] * T).sum() == 0
```

Btw, I think this is cleaner, more readable indexing for these kind of operations; though marginally (O(1)) slower since another view is constructed.

Comment: This only works if `T` has the same shape as `B`, but `T` is only as big as the dimension of a single `Tetromino`. Performance is only an issue since I'm implementing an AI and to optimize evaluation weights I have to run it very often. Currently a single turn takes ~ 300ms..

Comment: T and B both have ndim==2, no? And the shape is set equal through the selection of a window. If you need to evaluate multiple scenarios, you should definitely take a look at a scipy.convolve based solution.

Comment: My fault, the `3` was calculated wrong. Already twice as fast as before, but with some incorrect values for the special case y = -1 I need to deal with. Thanks

Comment: Dang, since the matrices look like [this](http://i.imgur.com/wjDP5Q2.png) there are a few more special cases, for example the vertical `I` can move to `x = -2` and still be valid..